# solr OR query over multiple fields

Tags: solr

Is it possible to search solr over two fields using two different words and get back only those results which contain one of them?

For example, if I have fields "name" and "age" , I want the results who have name='Mark' or age = '25' in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can try OR operator

```
/select?q=name:'Mark' OR age:'25'
```

Comment: can we use /select?q=name:'Mark'+age:'25'?@vinod